# Durret Example 1.7.4: problem guidance

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, fubini-tonelli-theorems

I have three questions regarding this example in Durret:

"Our last example shows that measurability is important or maybe that
some of the axioms of set theory are not as innocent as they seem.

Example 1.7.8. By the axiom of choice and the continuum hypothesis
one can define an order relation <' on (0,1) so that {x : x <'
y} is
countable for each y. Let X = Y = (0, 1), let A = B = the Borel
sets and µ1 = µ2 = Lebesgue measure. Let f(x, y) = 1 if x <'
y, = 0 otherwise. Since {x : x <'y} and $\{y : x <'y\}^{c}$   are countable,

$\int_X f(x, y) µ1(dx)=0 \ \ \ \ for\ all \ y$

$\int_Y f(x, y) µ2(dy)=1  \ \ \ \ for\ all \ x$"

1. How can we define an order relation like $<'$ on $(0,1)$ that $\{x:x<'y\}$ is countable for each y?(any example)
2. why isn't $\{x:x<'y\}$  a Borel set?
3. When f is not a measurable function, Is looking at this example as a counterexample meaningful? the integral on $\mu1\times\mu2$ measure is not even defined.

Here also is the image of the example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/714Cm.png

I really appreciate your help.(Sorry if this looks easy I'm new to Real analysis!)

Comment: Could you please **write** this supposed counterexample here. This link may help: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I just added a picture of the book. Do I still need to type it myself or the pic is enough? Sorry this my first time!

Comment: You don't **need** to type it, just as you don't **need** to post here. But if you don't then I won't even consider answering it. If you do put in the effort of typing it, then many more users will consider your question.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Got it.

Comment: $\{(x,y):x<'y\}$ isn't a Borel set.

Comment: @AnginaSeng yes, but why? Could you please explain more? Why isn't it a Borel set?

Comment: All the other conditions of Fubini/Tonelli hold, save the the function be measurable, yet the conclusion fails. So $f$ cannot be measurable, and as it's the indicator function of a set, that set cannot be measurable.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Thank you for your response. I appreciate it. But I was looking for a direct way to understand why $\{(x,y):x<'y\}$ is not a Borel set. I couldn't understand your reasoning that being an indicator function of a set make it to not be measurable? I mean $f=1_{(0,1)}$ is an indicator function of a set but it's still measurable.